# Change Format of date in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, datepicker

I am doing a project in `ASP.NET` , `c#`.

I have `.aspx` view in which i took a datpicker for approval Date.

I am fetching value of datepicker on OnChange event.

My datepicker in `.aspx` view look like:

```
 <%: Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.ApprovalDate).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("OnChangeDatePicker"))%>
```

I have a javascript function which am calling on OnChange event of datepicker.

```
function OnChangeDatePicker(e) {
   ApprovalDate = e.date;
}
```

In ApprovalDate am getting value of datepicker as :`Wed Aug 2 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013`

But i want the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript refer this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is -

```
var d = new Date('Wed Aug 2 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013');
var newDate = (d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+d.getFullYear();
```

EDIT, just found this works too:

```
var newDate =d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getDate():` Returns the date,`getMonth()`: Returns the month,`getFullYear()`: Returns the year

you can achieve your requirement by retrieving date month and year seperatly and then concating the three parts to get your format.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var date = ApprovalDate.getDate();
        var month = ApprovalDate .getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var year = ApprovalDate .getFullYear();
      var formattedDate=month+ "/" + date  + "/" + year;
    </script>
```

Comment: you are welcome,there are several methods you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript